# Mac Xampp Cakephp Bake Error

Tags: php, macos, cakephp, xampp

I ran this code on Mac and i am getting this error.

```
$ php cake.php bake all

$ cd /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/cakephp/app/Console/
Kgunner-iMac:Console kgunner$ php cake.php bake all

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are         *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Calcutta' for 'IST/5.0/no DST' instead in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/CacheEngine.php on line 60

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Calcutta' for 'IST/5.0/no DST' instead in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/CacheEngine.php on line 60

Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.6 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Bake All
---------------------------------------------------------------
Warning Error: PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in [/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php, line 175]

Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
#0     /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(260): Mysql->connect()
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php(105): DboSource->__construct(Array)
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(927): ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(864): ModelTask->getAllTables('default')
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(954): ModelTask->listAll('default')
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/BakeShell.php(150): ModelTask->getName('default')
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(437): BakeShell->all()
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(207): Shell->runCommand('all', Array)
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/app/Console/cake.php(36): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#10 {main}
```

I am getting this bake error. can anyone help how to fix it to bake properly.

Answer (score 2):

in your `database.php`, change your host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` , it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with you database configuration. configure your database properly

Comment: Db config is correct only, as the app normally in the web views is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Show us your db config. Check if the 'default' config is properly configured.

Pay attention that the correct location to run the console shell is from the app folder:

```
cd app/
./Console/cake bake all
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#the-cakephp-console